# find model number using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list, which I am trying to extract the item model number using regex

```
names=[
    'Honda Engine GX200 6.5HP 2.43" x 3/4" Crankshaft',
    'Honda New GX390 Engine Standard 1" Crank, Electric Start, Oil Alert',
    'Genuine Honda 79160-SHJ-A41 Temperature Driver Motor Assembly',
    'Auto Express Long Block Engine Crankcase with Cylinder Head Valves Fits Honda GX200 6.5 HP',
    'Honda 08207-10W30 PK2 Motor Oil'
]
```

The model number can only contain Upperletters,-,numbers

```
for name in names:
    model_num=re.search('([A-Z]+\d+\-[A-Z]*)',name).groups()[0]
```

my regex isn't working all the time. expected output is:

```
['GX200','GX390','79160-SHJ-A41','GX200','08207-10W30']
```

any help is much appreciated, if there is an easier way than regex that works too.

Comment: Sorry, but since the format of your strings varies too heavily, I don't think this is possible with regex. Try storing it as an object instead where you have `Manufacturer: "Honda Engine", Model: "GX200"` etc. Right now, there's no way using regex to solve this.

Comment: Is a model number always at least 5 characters long? If so `[A-Z\d-]{5,}` may work but that is pretty loose `JOHNNY` would match too.

Comment: @user3783243 No, modelnr can also be `79160-SHJ-A41` and manufacturer can be `Honda Engine` or `Auto Express Long Block Engine Crankcase with Cylinder Head Valves Fits Honda`

Comment: @Joel `at least 5 characters long`, stressing **at least**.

Comment: @Joel the names are extracted from this page https://www.amazon.com/slp/honda-motor/fkghdrvydu3ajxa  if it helps

Comment: @user3783243 Doesn't matter, look at all the examples. and check the link he just posted.

Comment: @Joel That's different than the question at hand. `['GX200','GX390','79160-SHJ-A41','GX200','08207-10W30']` is possible to get. From linked page 13 of 15 are identifiable.

Comment: @user3783243 that regex you posted almost worked

Comment: @madboy That likely is as close as you can get, and also can return false positives. You are trying to process language with a regex which is very difficult.

Comment: Well, take this ex. `Honda GX120UT1QX2 118cc GX120 Series OHV 3.5 HP Engine With Straight Keyed Shaft 3/4-Inch by 2-7/16-Inch Crankshaft`. Will get two matches regardless of how you want to match it, there's no structure to the matching, nothing to prefix, varying position of the `item model number` itself. I don't see how its possible, but if you want to give it a go, all the power to you bro.

Comment: To make things even harder, some of the examples contain a mix of upper and lower case letters (e.g. `Gx390-Qa2`).

Comment: @ekhumoro you ended all my hopes :(

Comment: @madboy The way to do this would be to grab the urls from the search, and then scrape the Product information table on the product page, which shows the Item model number separately.

Comment: @ekhumoro That was something I wanted to avoid but I guess no other choice, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @madboy Another possibility would be to use one of the [amazon python apis](https://pypi.org/project/python-amazon-simple-product-api/).

Comment: If you can't come up with any specific pattern requirements there is no solution. If the codes are strings that can have either numeric or alphabetic hyphen-separated values ending with an alphanumeric string, you may use `(?<!\S)(?:(?:\d+|[A-Z]+)-)*(?=\w{4})(?:\d+[A-Z]|[A-Z]+\d)[A-Z\d]*(?!\S)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L0l2iG/1).

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `re.compile` could improve speed a bit:

```py
find_model = re.compile(
    """
    [A-Z\d\-]+
    (?![a-z])  # Check that next char isn't lowercase to avoid getting false-positive head letter only
    """,
    re.VERBOSE,
)
for name in names:
    result = find_model.search(name)
    if result:
        model_num = result.group(0)
        print(model_num)
```